# Datables numeric sorting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

Using jQuery datables 1.9.0

```
$('#list').dataTable( {       
    "bJQueryUI": true, 
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]]       
} )
```

Getting this screen when I try to sort by id's

[image]

How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the [data type of particular column](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/sorting_sType.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Got me on the right track but find the code behind that link strange.  Why would it replace commas with a decimal place?

Answer (score 0):

Try `natural-desc`

```
$('#list').dataTable( {       
    "bJQueryUI": true, 
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "natural-desc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType": "natural-desc" },
        ....
    ]
} )
```

See: [Natural sorting](http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm-with-unicode-support/) from the [Plugin List](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting)

Comment: Yes, but when I click on ID column, it re-sorts whole column, and same result